# PHP While loop stops after two hours

Tags: php

I have the following script, that loops every 60 seconds. All works fine, but after two or three hours the script stops. I have no idea why.

```
<?php

// The worker will execute every X seconds:
$seconds = 60;

// We work out the micro seconds ready to be used by the 'usleep' function.
$micro = $seconds * 1000000;

while(true){

    try {
        $url = 'URL';
        $fields = array(
            "hi"=> 1,
            "world"=> 2,
        );
        //url-ify the data for the POST
        foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
        $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'&');

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
        curl_exec($ch);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $myFile = "/usr/share/test/filephp.txt";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("Can't open file");
        $stringData = "File updated at: " . time(). "\n";
        fwrite($fh, $stringData);
        fclose($fh);
    }




    // Now before we 'cycle' again, we'll sleep for a bit...
    usleep($micro);
}
```

The PHP script is executed with this command:

```
sudo -u root php -f /usr/share/test/test.php &
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you running the above code?

Comment: PHP will stop executing after a predetermined time unless you run it as a daemon

Comment: It's probably because of `max_execution_time` setting. But why don't you just run it as a cron job instead of a continuous loop?

Comment: Running this is as root is a bit of a code smell. That shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: It's not "a bit of a code smell" it's a huge no-no!

Comment: I can't use a cron. And this script will be for the end user, so I can't create a new user. It's a service (service start test) run by a test.sh that contains: "sudo -u root php -f /usr/share/test/test.php &"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap it in a bash script and remove the while loop altogether.

Script "wrapper":

```
#!/bin/bash

SECONDS=60
while [ 1 ]; do
    php -f /usr/share/test/test.php
    sleep $SECONDS
done
```

Then just call that script:

```
sudo -u root wrapper &
```

Comment: It is as stable as it gets.  You may need to use "nohup" to keep it from hanging up when the user session ends.

Comment: It's working. Thanks!
I added "&" just after the "done"